# Error 405 usando laravel 7 y jquery a pesar que usar metodo POST The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, jquery, post, laravel-7

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con laravel 7 y en su funcionalidad tiene que guardar la información personal de los usuarios que interacturan con este; uso la misma url para crear y o actualizar la información. Al enviar el formulario con jquery usando el método POST, en el ambiente local funciona, pero al subirlo al servidor me da como respuesta: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST". Lo curioso es que al enviar una variable por la misma url ('dominio.com/url/3') también funciona

Dato adicional: tengo un ssl activo.

RUTA:

`Route::post('/usuarios/actualizar/usuarios-datos/{id?}', 'UsersController@updateUsersData');`
//cuando id tiene un valor funciona, de lo contrario no

JQUERY:

```
$('#btn-users-data').on('click', function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var data = $('#form-users-data').serializeArray();

    for (var x in data) {
        formData.append(data[x].name, data[x].value);
    }

    var id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    toastr.warning('Procesando información');
    $.ajax({
            url: '/administracion/usuarios/actualizar/usuarios-datos/' + id,
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('.btn').attr('data-user-id', data);
            toastr.success('usuario actualizado');
            console.log("success");
        });
});
```

CONTROLADOR:

```
    public function updateUsersData(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'tipo_documento' => ['required'],
            'document' => ['required', Rule::unique('users_data')->ignore($request->id)],
            'ciudad_documento' => ['required'],
            'ciudad_residencia' => ['required'],
            'barrio' => ['required', 'max:60'],
            'direccion' => ['required', 'max:60'],
            'rh' => ['required', 'max:2'],
        ]);

        $request = StringEditController::string($request);

        if (isset($request->id)) {
            $usersData = UsersData::find($request->id);
        } else {
            $usersData = new UsersData();
            $usersData->user_id = $id;
        }

        $usersData->document_type = $request->tipo_documento;
        $usersData->document = $request->document;
        $usersData->document_city_id = $request->ciudad_documento;
        $usersData->residence_city_id = $request->ciudad_residencia;
        $usersData->address = $request->direccion;
        $usersData->neighborhood = $request->barrio;
        $usersData->RH = $request->rh;

        $usersData->save();

        return $usersData;
    }
```

FORMULARIO:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <form id="form-users-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $data_user->id ?? '' }}" name="id" id="id">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Tipo Documento</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tipo_documento" name="tipo_documento">
                        @if (isset($data_user->document_type))
                            <option value="{{ $data_user->document_type }}">{{ $data_user->document_type }}</option>
                        @else
                            <option value=''>Seleccciona</option>
                        @endif
                        <option value="CÉDULA ciudadania">CÉDULA CIUDADANÍA</option>
                        <option value="CÉDULA extranjeria">CÉDULA EXTRANJERIA</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Documento</label>
                    <input type="number" name="document" required class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        value="{{ $data_user->document ?? '' }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <small> <label>Departamento Documento</label></small>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm departamento" name="departamento">
                        @if (isset($data_user->departament_id))
                            <option value="{{ $data_user->document_departament_id }}">
                                {{ $data_user->document_departament_name }}
                            </option>
                        @else
                            <option>Seleccciona</option>
                        @endif
                        @foreach ($departaments as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="inputName">Ciudad Documento</label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm ciudad" name="ciudad_documento" required>
                        @if (isset($data_user->document_id_city))
                            <option value="{{ $data_user->document_id_city }}">{{ $data_user->document_city_name }}
                            </option>
                        @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <small> <label>Departamento Residencia</label></small>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm departamento" name="departamento">
                        @if (isset($data_user->recidence_departament_id))
                            <option value="{{ $data_user->recidence_departament_id }}">
                                {{ $data_user->recidence_departament_name }}
                            </option>
                        @else
                            <option>Seleccciona</option>
                        @endif
                        @foreach ($departaments as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputName">Ciudad Residencia </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm ciudad" name="ciudad_residencia" required>
                        @if (isset($data_user->recidence_city_id))
                            <option value="{{ $data_user->recidence_city_id }}">{{ $data_user->recidence_city_name }}
                            </option>
                        @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" required class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        value="{{ $data_user->address ?? '' }} " required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Barrio</label>
                    <input type="text" name="barrio" required class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        value="{{ $data_user->neighborhood ?? old('barrio') }}" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>R H</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rh" required class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        value="{{ $data_user->RH ?? '' }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn-users-data"
            data-user-id="{{ $user->id ?? '' }}">Actualizar</button>
    </div>
```

Actualización:
haciendo pruebas y observanbdo el analizador de red de firefox me he percatado que envia una solicitud en post y segido en get, perdón mi ignorancia pero no se si es un tipo de conflicto o un error mio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en post se detalla el envio de los campos con su respectivo valor pero en get me arroja el error.

---

Realmente no supe lo que sucedía, pero la hacer pruebas vi que al enviar un id al final de la url sucedía el error 405, lo que hice fue enviar el id en el formulario en un input hidden. No es lo mejor, pero me funciono.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que agregues tu formulario

Comment: Creo que no envías el token.

Comment: Ya agrege el formulario y en este se encuentra el token.

Comment: @Alejandro en tu form te esta faltando declarar el atributo `method` indicando que usarás `POST`, de otra forma el valor por defecto que se toma es `GET` trata corrigiendo eso

Comment: @BetaM agrege el method="POST" y no me funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno eso ya es un detalle menos, pero de que faltaba al ser una ruta post es un hecho

Comment: @Alejandro ¿seguro que ese es el form?, lo digo por que no encuentro el botón que tenga el id `#btn_user'`

Comment: @BetaM Si señor, ya actualize el codigo

Comment: es muy raro, tal vez el cache se quedo pegado, intenta con `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @FelipeUrcia la verdad ya probe con php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache  
php artisan config:cache  
php artisan view:clear  y no hay cambios

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que tienes dentro tu archivo web.php en la carpeta routes para saber qué ruta estás ocupando y ver si es la misma soportada por el formulario que usas

Comment: Prueba quitando `contentType: false, processData: false,` del AJAX

Comment: @CesarRomero ya lo intente pero me generar un  error ya que estoy usando formData(). Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué versión de jQuery estás utilizando?

Viendo en la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) encontré:

```
type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.
```

Sugiero cambies la propiedad `type` de tu llamada `$.ajax` por `method`.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ya realize el ajuste pero no me funciono, haciendo esrtas prueba confirmo de que el envio de datos es exitoso si al final de la url hay un numero ejemplo: dominio.com/ruta/1. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateUsersData($id = null, ...) {
   ...
   return Route::back()
}
```

los puntos continuos es lo que tengas implementado

Siempre debes regresar a la ruta original (GET), el navegador intentara enviar los datos sobre (POST) a la ruta (GET) para recuperar esta vista, y por supuesto dicha ruta no soporta POST

Comment: Un detalle que puedes tener es una ruta superior sobre get 
 `Route::get('/usuarios/actualizar/usuarios-datos/', .....)` por lo que te recomiendo que revises la jerarquía de las rutas

Answer (score 0):

Debes manejar el request en el controlador, preguntar si viene con dato, revisar el AUTH y si no quieres que entre lo sacas con un response.
Ahora si ese no es el problema recuerda mandar el csrf

```
<form action="/example" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```